# Cython from C pass unsigned char array to Python

Tags: c, python-3.x, cython

I want to pass unsigned char array to python from C.

```
cdef void c_recv_callback(unsigned char* buf, int len, void* py_func) with gil:
  printf("%X", buf)
  (<object>py_func)(buf)
```

I use the callback function to pass the unsigned char array. When I print out the buf in hexdecimal, it will show the value. But when pass to python and print out the result is b'\t'.

It is same with printing the buf use follow code.

```
printf("%s", buf)
```

Because It print out the tab. so how I can solve the problem.

Comment: %X prints not the value, but a part of the address buf.

Comment: In order to copy also the null-bytes to the python-object you need to use the syntax `buf[:len]` , see http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/strings.html

Comment: ead. Thank you very much. Now I solve the problem use the syntax.